# Can renderInContext: maintain corner radius and shadows?

Tags: ios, uilabel, image-rendering

I have a custom UILabel with round corners and a drop shadow. I'm using the properties on CALayer to achieve this. Next, I'm trying to save this as a UIImage using renderInContext:. The round corners are maintained, but a black background appears and a loose the drop shadow.

[image: Rendered Image]

Any thoughts on rendering the UILabel as an image but maintaining the shadow and rounded corners?

Here's the code I'm using to render the label:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(label.bounds.size, YES, 0);
[label.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get rounded corners by changing the second argument to "NO" in UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions.